# How to connect BigSQL using python

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, bigsql

I'm new to BigSQL.I would like to know how can I connect BigSQL using python 3.5

Thanks in advance,

Comment: First read [the official site of BigSQL](https://www.bigsql.org/docs/faq.jsp), it could help

Comment: Than you Guil23.It will help me to understand BigSQL,but it won't have any guide for python to BigSQL connection

Comment: BigSQL is just a Postgres distribution that contains a regular Postgres database server. You should be able to use any Postgres + Python tutorial

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name. I found command to connect postgress on server import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='yourdb', user='dbuser', password='abcd1234', host='server', port='5432', sslmode='require') but while I'm trying it by putting my details, I'm getting error message:  conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)

OperationalError